# JXL - Vertical and Horizontal Freeze on multiple sheets

Tags: java, excel, spreadsheet, jxl

```
SheetSettings settings = billSheet.getSettings();
settings.setHorizontalFreeze(1);
settings.setVerticalFreeze(8);
```

I have a sheet and its horizontal, vertical freeze set. Now i want to copy it to other sheet.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    workbook.copySheet(i, "Bill " + i, i + 1);
}
```

Here I will have 6 sheet with the same horizontal and vertical freeze (1 and 8).
However, when I open the exported excel file, only the first 2 sheet has freeze (same thing happens if I don't copy sheets but separately create and set freeze for them instead).
Is this an expected behavior of excel or jxl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. I forgot to mention, I tested it on LibreOffice.

It now runs correctly on Microsoft Excel.